# Returning SqlDataReader from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, sql, xml, wcf, sqldatareader

My method currently executes a stored procedure, the results of which I can access through the SqlDataReader. Is it now possible for me to convert this to XML? This is a wcf web service.

Comment: .NET web services exist to abstract this sort of thing out. You return a collection of objects from your function. The framework does the rest, where "the rest" includes returning that data of yours in either XML or JSON, depending on what the consumer asked for.

Comment: funny name btw :)

Comment: Ahh sorry GSerg - I'm going to ask a different question, as I don't seem to have read your original reply carefully enough. Would you recommend I use ADO .net entities to return the data from the SQL reader? And how can this service be consumed in a way that would request XML??

Comment: @the_joric - i swear he's just messing with us

Comment: IDataReader w/AutoMapper ---> .NET Object, then .NET Object w/WCF Serializer -----> XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, if you're requesting data out of a WCF service, it will serialize to XML for you, send over the wire & your WCF client will deserialize - it's all done for you, no interaction required.

If you just want to go from data to XML, you can load your SQL reader to a DataSet, then get the XML from that dataset (`DataSet.GetXml()`) - while probably not the best/fastest way, it's quick and dirty. For a single table of data, the .net `DataTable` also has a `WriteXml` method that writes to file, stream, etc.